# Impenting priority in where condition using laravel eloqent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am attempting to construct a query that uses a match against many columns to search the database.

also, I want to examine several search phrases in each column.

I have attempted to use this code:

```
public function searchLogicForAutosuggestion($searchQuery, &$query, $columns)
    {
        if (!is_null($searchQuery)) {
            $combinations = $this->generateSearchCombinations($searchQuery);
            if (count($combinations) > 0) {
                $query->where(function ($query) use ($columns, $searchQuery, $combinations) {
                    foreach ($columns as $index => $column) {
                        if ($index == 0) {
                            foreach ($combinations as $combIndex => $combination) {
                                if ($combIndex == 0) {
                                    $query->WhereRaw("match(`$column`) against( '\"$combination\"')");
                                } else {
                                    $query->orWhereRaw("match(`$column`) against( '\"$combination\"')");
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            foreach ($combinations as $combIndex => $combination) {
                                $query->orWhereRaw("match(`$column`) against( '\"$combination\"')");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }



     $query = Model::where('is_active', 1);
                if (!empty($request->search_term)) {
                    $query->where(function ($q) use ($request) {
                        $this->searchLogicForAutosuggestion($request->search_term, $q, ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']);
                    });
                }
```

this code generates a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    `id`, `name`
FROM
    `tablename`
WHERE
    `is_active` = 1
        AND ((MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC-228"' )
        OR MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC&228"' )
        OR MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC%228"' )
        OR MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC/228"' )
        OR MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC 228"' )
        OR MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC228"' )
        OR MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC-228"' )
        OR MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC&228"' )
        OR MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC%228"' )
        OR MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC/228"' )
        OR MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC 228"' )
        OR MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC228"' )))
GROUP BY `name`
LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0
```

and I want a query like this :

```
SELECT 
    `id`, `name`
FROM
    `tablename`
WHERE
    `is_active` = 1
        -- main and options is here
        AND (
           -- club column1 in ()
           ( MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC-228"' )
            OR MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC&228"' )
            OR MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC%228"' )
            OR MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC/228"' )
            OR MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC 228"' )
            OR MATCH (`column1`) AGAINST ('"ABC228"' ))
        AND -- i want to add AND here
            -- club column2 in ()
            (MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC-228"' )
            OR MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC&228"' )
            OR MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC%228"' )
            OR MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC/228"' )
            OR MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC 228"' )
            OR MATCH (`column2`) AGAINST ('"ABC228"' ))
        )
GROUP BY `name`
LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0
```

we want this because there are two different columns so If  both columns OR query run or match anything then return the value